# UWP Recursive File Search in C# is awfully slow

Tags: c#, list, file, uwp, directory

I am using the following code to search recursively the images in a selected folder. I have over 120000 images in that folder (Yes, I'm a photographer!) and it is incredibly slow, for e.g. I have to stop it after 10 minutes and it's not done yet. In comparison, my Python code (interpreted!) does the same in less than 2 minutes.

Is there any way to make this code more efficient? It works fine, that's ok, but only very slowly...

```
    public List<StorageFile> _allFiles;
    public List<StorageFile> ShuffledFiles;
    public int i = 0;
    public int ri = 0;
    public Boolean random = false;
    public int numfiles = 0;

    //Get the starting folder for recursive search
    private static async Task<StorageFolder> SelectFolderAsync()
    {
        var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker
        {
            SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop
        };
        //Selects the folder with a FolderPicker and returns the selected StorageFolder
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        return folder;
    }

    //Get the list of files recursively
    private async Task GetFilesInFolder(StorageFolder folder)
    {
        var items = await folder.GetItemsAsync();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            //If it's a folder, read each file in it and add them to the list of files "_allFiles"
            if (item is StorageFile )
            {
                StorageFile typetest = item as StorageFile;
                String ext = typetest.FileType.ToLower();
                if ((ext == ".jpg") || (ext == ".jpeg") || (ext == ".tiff") || (ext == ".cr2") || (ext == ".nef") || (ext == ".bmp") || (ext == ".png"))
                { _allFiles.Add(item as StorageFile);
                    numfiles = numfiles + 1;
                    //Display the file count so I can track where it's at...
                    cmdbar.Content = "Number of slides:"+numfiles.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            //otherwise, recursively search the folder
                await GetFilesInFolder(item as StorageFolder);
        }
    }


    //Select the directory, load the files and display the first file
    private async void LoadMediaFile(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFolder root = await SelectFolderAsync();
        //Initialises the file list _allFiles, the filecount numfiles, and the pointers to the list i and ri
        _allFiles = new List<StorageFile>();
        numfiles = 0;
        //Reads the files recursively into the list
        await GetFilesInFolder(root);
    }
```

Comment: Definietely use a SearchQuery as the below answer says - but also stick .ConfigureAwait(false) on to the end of your tasks in GetFilesInFolder to prevent massive amounts of context switching. For example, `await folder.GetItemsAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false)` and `await GetFilesInFolder(item as StorageFolder).ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: This sounds interesting, however I'm getting  "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread" as error... sorry I'm not sure what I'm doing with this...

Comment: .ConfigureAwait(false) essentially tells the code to not care about returning itself to the thread it originated from which is relatively expensive, and very noticeable in high yield loops. In this case it means it doesn't return to the UI thread, which means cmdbar.Content needs to be set using Dispatcher.RunAsync(....). (Do not await it). As long as you don't ConfigureAwait in LoadMediaFile itself that should be the only place with need for Dispatching.

Comment: Cool! ConfigureAwait makes a significant difference. However, I still don't understand why my python code is soooo much faster? Python is interpreted which should make it slower.

Comment: File access is Sandboxed in UWP and interops through a separate process (RuntimeBroker.exe), so it's going to be slower. System.IO in UWP is also implemented using StorageFile API's so there's no benefit too it (it's actually marginally slower if you're correctly configuring awaits). But using the Windows Search API's to pre-filter by File Type, do deep searching, and use the search index should give even more boost.

Comment: Thanks Johnny, will give this a try! :)

Comment: Johnny, sorry for my ignorance, but will using the Window Search API result in my app not being UWP compliant?

Comment: Sorry, by that I meant the API's in `Windows.Storage.Search` which run upon the Windows Search tech. https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FileSearch has some samples with rather "basic" docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-listing-files-and-folders . Be sure to check out the article of Fast File property access too. You'll get benefits of returning all results in a single batch (though at 10,000 files you should page for memory reasons), but probably lose progress tracking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have so many photo that I quickly can test but two things you can try.

1. Use the System.IO namespace; I noticed some improvements improvements in my app when I switched to that API.
2. Don't manually iterate over it by try to use the seaerch api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-listing-files-and-folders#query-files-in-a-location-and-enumerate-matching-files (I think would be the best approach)

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, it's only marginally faster....

Should I try to collect only the filenames (strings) in a list instead of the StorageFolder? Would this help because of memory management of creating a larger object? Or is this related to the disk I/O speed?

Doing something like this with Windows Explorer takes a minute or two for these folders, so there's gotta be a  faster way...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make this code more efficient?

Derive from [**Universal Windows Platform - File System Monitoring in Universal Windows Platform Apps**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790201)

> The system is now able to provide a list of all the changes that are happening in a library, from a picture being taken all the way up to entire folders being deleted. This is a huge help if you’re looking to build a cloud backup provider, track files being moved off the device or even just display the most recent photos.

It means that the system will create database to record the index of the file. And Windows Storage API has provide [`CreateFileQueryWithOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.createfilequerywithoptions) that use file index to query file efficiently.

```
StorageFolder photos = KnownFolders.CameraRoll;
// Create a query containing all the files your app will be tracking
QueryOptions option = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery,
  supportedExtentions);
option.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Shallow;
// This is important because you are going to use indexer for notifications
option.IndexerOption = IndexerOption.UseIndexerWhenAvailable;
StorageFileQueryResult resultSet =
  photos.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(option);
// Indicate to the system the app is ready to change track
await resultSet.GetFilesAsync(0, 1);
// Attach an event handler for when something changes on the system
resultSet.ContentsChanged += resultSet_ContentsChanged;
```

And this related blog you could refer.
  [**Change Tracking: More Betterness**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adamdwilson/2016/10/04/change-tracking-more-betterness/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, tried using the Windows.Storage.Search API. Using the code below, I scan a subtree of 70,000 files in 1 min 45 sec. The recursive code above (in my original question) takes 1 min 32 sec (faster...!). Interestingly enough, I would have thought the recursive code would have taken more time and resources because it has more overhead?!?!?!

***And my Python interpreted code takes only 3 seconds!!! For the same thing!!!***

There has got to be a better way, no? Microsoft engineers around, any hints?

```
    //This code is actually taken almost literally from the Microsoft example 
    // given here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.search.queryoptions
   private async Task GetFilesInFolder(StorageFolder folder)
    {
            List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
            fileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            fileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            fileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            fileTypeFilter.Add(".tiff");
            fileTypeFilter.Add(".nef");
            fileTypeFilter.Add(".cr2");
            fileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
            QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, fileTypeFilter);
            queryOptions.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep;
            queryOptions.IndexerOption = IndexerOption.UseIndexerWhenAvailable;
            StorageFileQueryResult queryResult = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
            var files = await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();

            if (files.Count == 0)
            {
                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { cmdbar.Content = "Nothing found!" ; });
            }
            else
            {
                // Add each file to the list of files (this takes 2 seconds)
                foreach (StorageFile file in files)
                {
                    _allFiles.Add(file as StorageFile);
                    numfiles = numfiles + 1;
                    //Display the file count so I can track where it's at...
                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { cmdbar.Content = "Number of slides:" + numfiles.ToString(); });
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Give this a shot: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adamdwilson/2017/12/20/fast-file-enumeration-with-partially-initialized-storagefiles/

Comment: uhhhh!!! Sounds promising George! Will give it a shot and report for sure!

Comment: I did modify the code to use this approach, and it is indeed about 10x faster. However, the files must be indexed using the Windows Indexer. And the other thing that makes me upset is that my Python app, intepreted is 100x faster (I timed it!) than the UWP native app. It's like if Microsoft is willingly slowing down the computer....?!?!?

Comment: I ended up having the same problem. I'm trying to enumerate videos and the folder is not indexed. I had to modify this to not use the index and I'm pretty sure I've lost the speed increase.