# UWP Executing long: background or Extended Execution

Tags: c#, uwp, background-process

I have developed an application that needs to read an extensive list of files (loading images) before it starts running. With UWP, the user has to wait with the window in the foreground until everything is loaded because it is in suspended state when not in the foreground.

After much reading, I'm trying to decide which route to take. I could use the "Extended Execution" approach or start a background task.

Anyone could point me on the plus and minuses of each approach, or any other recommendation?

Comment: First, why does it need to load all the images before user can see anything on the screen? Assume this app loads movie posters from a website - so it takes some time, it can should a blank `GridView` to the user, and user can see the posters are inserted into the `GridView` one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very good explanation here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt590969.aspx

Very useful. Thanks Phil for pointing me in the right direction. It's working great.

Answer (score 0):

Just show a wait message as the window content. Show a nice company logo and 'Please wait, initialising' as a message. Even better, show a percentage indicator so the user gets a feel for how long it will take to complete. When finished you replace the window content with the real content of the application.

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to do this is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214932/uwp-recursive-file-search-in-c-sharp-is-awfully-slow?noredirect=1#comment91453470_52214932

So posting a wait sign does not help. A user will likely switch application while the recursive search is going on, and when he/she does this with a UWP app, the search is put in "suspended" mode. 

So, my question is: what is the difference between the two approaches (background vs Extended Execution) and which is the preferred one for this case.

Comment: I think you want to use Extended Execution. A background task runs in a separate process and can be run without your application running at all. Extended Execution allows your app to run when minimized.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Will look into this. I know there are some Windows Samples of this on github, just wasn't sure which was the best strategy.